# Google Earth Pro is not working in Gnome 41 wayland session Works fine in Xorg on Devuan Linux

Tags: debian, x11, wayland, devuan

**Synaptic, Google Earth, xterm etc are not working in Gnome wayland sessions.**

I am using Devuan Daedalus (Testing) and it is stable, except for some offending apps like synaptic, xterm, Google Earth Pro etc which are not working. I can see these processes are running in the background, but no drawing (UI) works. However, these apps works fine in X11 (Xorg) session. On Ubuntu 21.04 with the same Gnome-40, these apps are working.

```
:~# ps aux |grep earth
devuan   6623  0.0  0.0   6768  3176 pts/1    S+   11:55   0:00 /bin/bash /usr/bin/google-earth-pro
devuan   6626 20.2  2.2 3425868 178644 pts/1  Sl+  11:55   0:01 /opt/google/earth/pro/googleearth-bin

:~# ps aux |grep xterm
devuan   6741  0.3  0.1  24588 10296 pts/1    S+   11:56   0:00 xterm

:~# ps aux |grep synaptic
devuan   6781  0.0  0.0   2432   672 pts/1    S+   11:57   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/synaptic-pkexec
root      6782  8.7  1.4 475756 119188 pts/1   Sl+  11:57   0:01 /usr/sbin/synaptic
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @jsotola I have added the context. In brief - Synaptic, Earth, xterm are some of the apps not working in Gnome-41 wayland session. I'm asking for a solution. Same apps works fine in Ubuntu with Gnome-40.